# How do I create an index for an embedded object in Couchbase?

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

I have 1 million documents in the bucket.

I want to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE type = 'toy' AND material = 'plastic' AND color = 'red' AND weight = '200gr' AND height = '5cm' AND width = '15cm'
```

"attributes" is an object embedded within the document.

Example:

> "type": "toy",
>  "other key": "other value",
>  "other key": "other
>   value",
>  "attributes": {
>        "material": "plastic",
>     "color": "red",
>      "weight": "200gr",
>       "height": "5cm",
>     "width": "15cm"
> }
>  "other key": "other value",
>  "other key":
>   "other value"

How do I create the index in Query Workbench to get the fastest possible response time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a document like the following:

```
{
    "type": "toy",
        "attributes": {
        "material": "plastic",
        "color": "red",
        "weight": "200gr",
        "height": "5cm",
        "width": "15cm"
    }
}
```

And your query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` t WHERE t.type = 'toy' AND t.attributes.material = 'plastic' AND t.attributes.color = 'red'AND t.attributes.weight = '200gr' AND t.attributes.height = '5cm' AND t.attributes.width = '15cm'
```

An index for it will be similar to this one:

```
create index toysIndex on `test`(type, attributes.material, attributes.color, attributes.weight, attributes.height, attributes.width  ) USING GSI;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

deniswsrosa's suggestion will definitely work, but you can improve on it a bit by moving the type specification into the WHERE clause of the index. That way, the index of these fields will only include objects of type 'toy'; other types of objects will not be indexed. This will make the index somewhat smaller because it is more specific. The type="toy" clause will still be considered in the use of the index.

Like this:

```
create index toysIndex on test(attributes.material, attributes.color,
attributes.weight, attributes.height, attributes.width  ) 
where type = 'toy';
```

Note that you don't need the back-ticks around "test". Also, GSI indexes are the default.